# What is Sequence length in LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

The dimensions for the input data for LSTM are [Batch Size, Sequence Length, Input Dimension] in tensorflow.

1. What is the meaning of Sequence Length & Input Dimension ?
2. How do we assign the values to them if my input data is of the form :
   [[[1.23] [2.24] [5.68] [9.54] [6.90] [7.74] [3.26]]] ?

Comment: Imagine you're forecasting stock prices based on features up to a given day. Let's assume you use 3 features, e.g. previous closing price, current price and industry. Also, even though you might have dozens of thousands of such features, i.e. thousands of stock tickers collected over thousands of days, let's suppose you enter a 10-day sequence into the network at a time, and for performance, you group 100 such batches of 10 days' features to pass to the network. In such a scenario: Batch = 100, Sequence Length = 10, Input Dimension = 3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LSTMs are a subclass of recurrent neural networks. Recurrent neural nets are by definition applied on *sequential* data, which without loss of generality means data samples that change over a time axis. A full history of a data sample is then described by the sample values over a finite time window, i.e. if your data live in an N-dimensional space and evolve over t-time steps, your input representation must be of shape (num_samples, t, N).

Your data does not fit the above description. I assume, however, that this representation means you have a scalar value x which evolves over 7 time instances, such that x[0] = 1.23, x[1] = 2.24, etc.

If that is the case, you need to reshape your input such that instead of a list of 7 elements, you have an array of shape (7,1). Then, your full data can be described by a 3rd order tensor of shape (num_samples, 7, 1) which can be accepted by a LSTM.

Comment: should N be assigned to always 1 if we are dealing with text embeddings for instance?

Comment: @Nihat That depends. How many dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put seq_len is number of time steps that will be inputted into LSTM network, Let's understand this by example...
Suppose you are doing a sentiment classification using LSTM.
Your input sentence to the network is =["I hate to eat apples"]. Every single token would be fed as input at each timestep, So accordingly here the seq_Len would total number of tokens in a sentence that is 5.
Coming to the input_dim you might know we can't directly feed words to the netowrk you would need to encode those words into numbers. In Pytorch/tensorflow embedding layers are used where we have to specify embedding dimension.
Suppose your embedding dimension is 50 that means that embedding layer will take index of respective token and convert it into vector representation of size 50. So the input dim to LSTM network would become 50.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following sequence:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And we want to train an LSTM model to predict the next number in the sequence based on the previous numbers. We'll choose a sequence length of 3 for this example.

So, we would organize our data into input-output pairs like this:

```
Input   Output
[1, 2, 3]   4
[2, 3, 4]   5
[3, 4, 5]   6
[4, 5, 6]   7
[5, 6, 7]   8
[6, 7, 8]   9
[7, 8, 9]   10
```

Each input sequence contains three numbers, and the corresponding output is the number that follows the input sequence in the original sequence.

We would then feed these input-output pairs into the LSTM model during training. The LSTM model learns to capture the patterns in the sequences and predict the next number in the sequence based on the previous numbers.

During inference, if we provide the model with a sequence like
[8,9,10], it should predict the next number in the sequence, which is
11 in this case.